# How to link the libraries for calling Python from C or C++

Tags: c, python-3.x

I am interested in writing a GIMP plug-in that calls the scikit-image Python library. To that end, I would like to call Python from C. I am having trouble linking the libraries. I found what seems to be the Python library for C on my system. The path on my system is ~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/libpython3.8.a. When I link to this, it resolves the calls like PyDecodeLocale. However, it still has undefined references to math functions like pow, atan2, etc and also to PyImport_FindSharedFuncptr, etc. I do not know if this is the right library to link. My source code is a simple hello world:

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// #include "/home/anna_user2/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/include/python3.8/Python.h"
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                       "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {
        exit(120);
    }
    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to link libmath(`-lmath` in gcc) for math functions. Can you post the command you're running?

Comment: gcc hello.cpp -lmath ~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/libpython3.8.a It says cannot find -lmath

Comment: gcc hello.cpp -Lmath ~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/libpython3.8.a
 It still cannot find the math functions

Comment: Making progress... it can find the math functions but not the threading stuff, like pthread_sigmask. THe command I used is g++ hello.cpp -Lmath ~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/libpython3.8.a

Comment: Tried g++ hello.cpp -LDFLAGS=-pthread -lpthread ~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/libpython3.8.a

Answer (score 0):

THis works:

gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -fPIC mylib.c -o mylib.o
gcc -shared mylib.o -o mylib.so